# Schema Changes Not Replicating with Kafka Connect

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

The goal is: MySQL -> Kafka -> MySQL. The sink destination should be up to date with production.

Inserting and deleting records is fine, but I am having issues with schema changes, such as a dropped column. The changes are not replicating to the sink destination.

My source:

```
{
    "name": "hub-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
        "database.hostname": "mysql",
        "database.port": "3306",
        "database.user": "debezium",
        "database.password": "dbz",
        "database.server.id": "42",
        "database.server.name": "study",
        "database.include.list": "companyHub",
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "broker:29092",
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "dbhistory.study",
        "include.schema.changes": "true"
    }
}
```

My sink

```
{
    "name": "companyHub-sink",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://172.18.141.102:3306/Hub",
        "connection.user": "user",
        "connection.password": "passaword",
        "topics": "study.companyHub.countryTaxes, study.companyHub.addresses",
        "auto.create": "true",
        "auto.evolve": "true",
        "delete.enabled": "true",
        "insert.mode": "upsert",
        "pk.fields": "id",
        "pk.mode": "record_key",
        "transforms": "dropPrefix, unwrap",
        "transforms.dropPrefix.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
        "transforms.dropPrefix.regex":"study.companyHub.(.*)$",
        "transforms.dropPrefix.replacement":"$1",
        "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
        "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false",
        "transforms.unwrap.delete.handling.mode": "rewrite"
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Auto-creation and Auto-evoluton
Tip

Make sure the JDBC user has the appropriate permissions for DDL.

If auto.create is enabled, the connector can CREATE the destination table if it is found to be missing. The creation takes place online with records being consumed from the topic, since the connector uses the record schema as a basis for the table definition. Primary keys are specified based on the key configuration settings.

If auto.evolve is enabled, the connector can perform limited auto-evolution by issuing ALTER on the destination table when it encounters a record for which a column is found to be missing. Since data-type changes and removal of columns can be dangerous, the connector does not attempt to perform such evolutions on the table. Addition of primary key constraints is also not attempted. In contrast, if auto.evolve is disabled no evolution is performed and the connector task fails with an error stating the missing columns.

For both auto-creation and auto-evolution, the nullability of a column is based on the optionality of the corresponding field in the schema, and default values are also specified based on the default value of the corresponding field if applicable. We use the following mapping from Connect schema types to database-specific types:

Schema Type MySQL   Oracle  PostgreSQL  SQLite  SQL Server  Vertica

Auto-creation or auto-evolution is not supported for databases not mentioned here.

Important

For backwards-compatible table schema evolution, new fields in record schemas must be optional or have a default value. If you need to delete a field, the table schema should be manually altered to either drop the corresponding column, assign it a default value, or make it nullable.

Comment: "Since data-type changes and removal of columns can be dangerous, the connector does not attempt to perform such evolutions on the table"

Comment: Thanks... are you saying it's not possible?

Comment: according to the jdbc sink connector document,  altering for drop column is not supported, although I found out the following document that seems to try to tackle this matter  , but notice it is up to you to handle the ddl changes. https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/mysql.html#mysql-schema-change-topic

Comment: ... Schema change topic